# If I change the default ciphers on a Windows client PC, is there a way I can test the change?

Tags: ssl

Is the a tool that allows me to test the change or an online application that tests the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over a server {or just know of one that you can connect to) that allows what you disabled, or disallows what you enabled, you can connect to it before and after the change then look at your browser (or app's) 'info on connection' to see what the impact was. This is useful especially to see if a change you made had the desired effect. You could instead use a tool like [SSL TAP](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/ssltap.html%20SSLTAP) or [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over a server that would allow me such testing. The link to SSL Tap is broken. How does OpenSSL allow me to test ciphers?

Comment: Weird... pasted URL in from my browser: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/ssltap.html  should work. If you don't have control over a server you need only find one that allows what you've disabled (or the reverse). Alternatively you can use a tool like OpenSSL and have it act as an SSL server then connect to it with your client and play with the server or client configs to test your changes.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a read of it. Are you able to answer the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576687/is-a-change-required-only-in-the-code-of-a-web-application-to-support-hsts?